# CORS configuration problem: within the same bucket, one folder is throwing up Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors, the other doesn't

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've setup S3 + cloudfront so that I can host media objects used by a website running on a different server. My website uses AJAX to retrieve images & sounds from S3, so I had to set up CORS for the first time to try to resolve the Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors I was getting.

I read all the instructions, and got it working with a *really* basic CORS configuration rule:

```
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
</CORSRule>
```

And was psyched because I was now able to use AJAX to retrieve my files inside of **bucket**/test/ e.g.
https://d1wo7z5fsnzixj.cloudfront.net/test/loop-1/5.mp3

But, I'm still getting origin access errors when trying to retrieve files inside of **bucket**/live/ e.g.
https://d1wo7z5fsnzixj.cloudfront.net/shepardspi/loop-1/5.mp3

Why can't I use AJAX to retrieve the second file, but the first one works fine? Is there some folder-level CORS configuration I have to do?

Comment: Why are you getting CORS errors for `GET`? Either way, try invalidating CloudFront cache first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @kichik. Now it seems to be working. I didn't know there were synchronization issues that sometimes needed to be waited out. As for why I was getting CORS errors for GET, it's because an AJAX script was doing those GET requests.